# How to debug silent crash

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, pyqt, pycharm

I have a Python3.4 and PyQt5 application. This application communicate with an embedded device (Send and receive some frames).

I have a method (run from a QThread) to retrieve the device events ( It can be 10 events or more than 600 ). This methode work well in "release" mode.
But when I start the program in "debug" mode with Pycharm, it will work without breakpoint but will crash with the exit code 0 if I put a breakpoint.

I have a retry button to launch this process. 
So in release mode if I retry again and again it will also fail with the the exit code 0.

Moreover, the application doesn't crash each time at the same moment, if the amount of data to read from the device is large, the soft will crash earlier, else it will be longer.

So I was thinking about memory, but I can't catch any exception.
I tried to re-raise every exception in my program, nothing, so I tried to add thoses lines in my main :

```
def on_exception_triggered(type_except, value, tb):
    import traceback
    trace = "".join(traceback.format_exception(type_except, value, tb))
    print("ERROR HOOKED : ", trace)
    sys.__excepthook__(type_except, value, tb)

sys.excepthook = on_exception_triggered
```

But it catch nothing more

Comment: What type of breakpoint are you using and how are you configuring it?

Comment: The default PyCharm breakpoints, i don't configure it. i just click where i want to put my breakpoint then launch the program in debug mode

Comment: That could be why. It could also depend on where you're putting the breakpoint. I would recommend checking out the PyCharm docs on [using breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/using-breakpoints.html) -- You can configure a breakpoint to suspend all threads, or just the thread that meets the breakpoint conditions (conditions are also configurable)

Comment: That's interresting but as it also crash on release mode without breakpoint, i don't think that's it. I was using a Python line breakpoint, and just tried some different configuration, it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the best thing that you can do is try to make your code independent from pyqt and debug it look for issues fix them and make connection with pyqt, because otherwise even if your code works fine you will get just the interface on a screen and you can not see what happen